# "unused arguments" error when using a method

Tags: r

This is really a mystery for me. I have defined my method like this (for class "graf"):

```
addStatistics <- function(x) UseMethod("addStatistics")
addStatistics.graf <- function (x, stat_name = NULL, value = NULL)
{
    if (stat_name == "env_coef_delta_mnll") {
        x$env_coef_delta_mnll <- value
    }
    x
}
```

I am calling the method like this, and getting an error:

```
addStatistics(m, "env_coef_delta_mnll", 0)
#Error in addStatistics(m, "env_coef_delta_mnll", 0) : 
#  unused arguments ("env_coef_delta_mnll", 0)
```

Why the method doesn't accept those supplied arguments and says they are "unused"?

Comment: The signatures must match.  Add `...` to the end of the generic's signature.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Which signatures? The function call perfectly matches the definition.

Comment: It does not.. The generic only has x and the method has additional args.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of solving the problem. Apparently you are creating a setter function, so I will change the generic a bit.

```
`addStatistics<-` <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("addStatistics<-")
`addStatistics<-.graf` <- function (x, stat_name = NULL, value = NULL)
{
  if (stat_name == "env_coef_delta_mnll") {
    x$env_coef_delta_mnll <- value
  }
  x
}

as.graf <- function(x){
  class(x) <- "graf"
  x
}
x <- as.graf(list())

addStatistics(x, "env_coef_delta_mnll") <- 1234
x
#$env_coef_delta_mnll
#[1] 1234
#
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "graf"
```

Comment: OK, thanks, this is definitely much better! But again, why my code in the question doesn't work?

Comment: @TMS Because of what G.Grothendiek said in his comments, the signature of the generic must have the dots argument in order to predict more arguments, depending on the method. unless you know in advance all possible methods that can be written for that generic.

Answer (score 0):

@GGrothendieck beat me to the punch, but here's a reprex to prove it;

```r
addStatistics <- function(...) UseMethod("addStatistics")

addStatistics.graf <- function (x, stat_name, value)
{
  if(!missing(stat_name)){
    if (stat_name == "env_coef_delta_mnll") {
        x$env_coef_delta_mnll <- value
    }}
    x
}

m <- list(env_coef_delta_mnll = 3)
class(m) <- "graf"

addStatistics(m, stat_name = "env_coef_delta_mnll", 4)
#> $env_coef_delta_mnll
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "graf"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>